# Is there a way to select multiple fields from a database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, variables

**The problem: selecting multiple Database fields.**

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
 var q = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM items';
 connection.query(q, function (error, results) {
 if (error) throw error;
 var count= results[0].count;
 res.render("home", {count:count});
 });
});
```

This is the route that I'm working in. As it is now, it works. But I can not find how to get the rest of the values out of the item table such as name and price. Please help.

Comment: It sounds like you're new to SQL. I would start with the mysql documentation. Here's the SELECT documentation. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: since you're selecting a count of the number of rows (with the COUNT() function), you can't select actual field values at the same time. So you either get back a count of the rows, or you get back the actual content of the rows e.g. using `SELECT name, price FROM items`

Comment: that's the better answer. Mine wouldn't have even worked

Answer (score 0):

Of course, `SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM items;` returns only one row, with one column named `count`. That column contains a number; the number of rows in the `items` table. That's what you asked for.

If you want the detail, you could try `SELECT * FROM items;` as your query. In this case the `result` contains an array of objects, one for each row retrieved.

Try something like this (**not debugged**):

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
 var q = 'SELECT * FROM items;';
 connection.query(q, function (error, results) {
 if (error) throw error;
 var count= results.length;
 for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
   let row = results[i];
   /* don't know what's in your rows, therefore I give you console.log */
   console.log ('row', i, row);
 }
 res.render("home", {count:count});
 });
});
```

**Pro tip**: Avoid `SELECT *`. Instead give a list of the columns you want.